# Zend Framework Controller to Module routing

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, module, routes, controllers

So i have been doing my best trying to absorb as much as i can about the Zend Framework which is pretty new to me, i'm about two weeks in since my first attempts and being doing well so far.

However i have run into a small issue i just can't figure out.

So here's the deal, i have a standard Zend Framework project with a number of modules in it. Like this :

```
- Project
- - Application
- - - configs
- - - controllers
- - - - IndexController
- - - - WMSController
- - - forms
- - - layouts
- - - models
- - - modules
- - - - content
- - - - - controllers
- - - - - - IndexController
- - - - - models
- - - - - views
- - - - - Bootstrap
- - - views
- - - bootstrap
- - public

etc..
```

Now i have a simple test link set in the view for the WMSController wich is supposed to direct someone klicking it to the IndexController of the content module.

```
<a href="wms/content"> test link to content module</a>
```

Now as you can probably see this link is NOT going to work since it is pointing towards localhost/wms/content which would be the content action in the WMSController which doesn't exist at this moment.

Now what i want to do is to make the wms/content actually point towards the IndexController of the content module. Why? Well i simply do not want a user to type localhost/content to get to the content module which is part of the WMS. I want to force them to get trough the WMS controller first.

I have read numerous things about routing being the solution using the bootstrap or the autoloader but pretty much all of them simply help you with pointing a certain url to a specific action in a specific controller.

What i want is a url to point to a specific action in a specific controller in a specific module.

NOTE: All the other controllers and views are still the default generated versions with no changes made to them yet!

If anyone could show me a code example of how this is done it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use the [Router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html)?

Comment: Similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372055/cannot-load-modules-index-action-for-zend-framework-module/9436169#9436169 Go through the answer, my guess it's apache's the mod_rewrite module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you simply want `/wms/content` to point to module ***content*** controller ***Index*** action ***index***. This is a case where a simple router will work(at least until you want to get more complex)

In your application.ini add these lines:

```
resources.router.routes.content.route = "wms/content"
resources.router.routes.content.defaults.module = "content" 
resources.router.routes.content.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.content.defaults.action = "index"
```

this is the easiest way to build a custom route. 
**Note:**The 4th parameter from the left is the name of the route, so if you use it with a method that allows using route names (the url() helper for example) you can just use the route name.
 `$this->url(array(), 'content');`

This is how you would use a named route, personally I would probably consider renaming my module *wms* (if possible and practical) and just redirecting there from the default Index controller. Because once you start with named and custom routes it's hard to quit...

Answer (score 0):

From your question that you

> want to force them to get trough the WMS controller first

You can do one thing. Whatever you want to do in WMSController whenever a user types localhost/content/** you can put it in the parent class for ALL THE CONTROLLERS IN MODULE: 'CONTENT'. This way you can check for something/ perform operations everytime a request comes to this controller (no matter if the user wanted to go to the other module.)

class Content_AnyController extends MyControllers_Controller_Action_Admin{
        ....
   }

where

```
class Reviewmo_Controller_Action extends Zend_Controller_Action{ 
    public function init(){
    //Things you want to do each time
    }

}
```

This is what I think you want to achieve because if you want to just simply redirect to WMSController's ContentAction you can simply redirect to that controller.